# jQuery Auto Rotating SWFs

Tags: jquery

Im trying to find a tutorial or demo of jQuery auto rotating banner images/SWFs >>>WITHOUT OVERLAYING<<< each image/SWF that slows down my browser.

I currently have an old rotating SWF banners based on javascript with transition effect (on my website) that overlays on top of each image/SWF and it is killing my computer/browser. The longer they overlay each other, it freezes the browser app and have to close/reopen it.

Something like a_banner rotates up front for few sec then the b_banner rotates next and the a_banner disappears behind it, rather than staying behind the b_banner.

I know there are tons of jQuery rotating banner, but they are not what Im looking for technically.

Thanks and appreciate it.

Comment: What code have you tried?  Any snippets we can take a look at to help you on your way?

Comment: its a old javascript and wanted something new and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Well without knowing a little more, I guess an idea would be to use ajax methods to feed html content of a swf object into a div using jQuery.  A process flow would look something like...
render a placeholder where swfs will live.  have a javascript method setup to run every n seconds (using setTimeout) to call a web service that streams out html content.  The html content would be the html representation of a swf (....etc).  Then you can use jQuery to dispose of the old flash object and replace it with the new content.

How's that sound?